# How to receive all data after TCP connection has been closed by the peer?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, tcp, polling

Running some production code I faced the following problem: 
When sending HTTP requests to some server, server immediately closes the connection after sending response, which, for some reason, results in data loss.

Analyzing TCP dumps i can see that conversation goes as this:
client request

server ack

server push

server fin, ack (sent after ~0.000020 secs after previous push)

As the result my code can't get data sent by the server, (i'm guessing because of the small delay after push POLLHUP event might go before POLLIN?)

Trying to mimic the problem I've written the following code:
(It mimics the client behaviour on my side)
client:

```py
import time
import socket

from errno import EAGAIN
from select import poll, POLLIN, POLLPRI, POLLERR, POLLHUP, POLLNVAL


def main(buf=""):
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.setblocking(False)
    client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)

    polling_object = poll()
    polling_object.register(client, POLLPRI | POLLIN | POLLERR | POLLHUP)

    in_buf = ""
    sock_closed = False
    try:
        client.connect(("127.0.0.1", 8877))
    except socket.error, e:
        pass

    while True and not sock_closed:
        events = polling_object.poll(0)
        for _, e in events:
            if e & (POLLIN | POLLPRI):
                while True:
                    try:
                        data = client.recv(1024)
                        if data:
                            in_buf += data
                        elif data == "":
                            client.close()
                            sock_closed = True
                            break
                    except socket.error, e:
                        if e.args[0] == EAGAIN:
                            break
                        else:
                            raise
            elif e & (POLLERR|POLLHUP|POLLNVAL):
                client.close()
                sock_closed = True

        if buf and not sock_closed:
            try:
                b_sent = client.send(buf)
                if b_sent == len(buf):
                    buf = ""
                else:
                    buf = buf[b_sent:]
            except socket.error, e:
                if e.args[0] != EAGAIN:
                    client.close()
                    sock_closed = True

        time.sleep(0.5)
        if sock_closed:
            return in_buf


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        buf = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        buf = 'hello'

    print main(buf)
```

server

```py
import datetime
import time
import socket


def main():
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server.bind(("127.0.0.1", 8877))
    server.listen(0)
    client, _ = server.accept()
    t1 = time.time()
    data = ""
    while not data:
        data += client.recv(1024)
    print "recv data %s" % data
    client.sendall('{"ok": 1}')
    t2 = time.time()
    client.close()
    t3 = time.time()
    server.close()

    return t1, t2, t3


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c_r, d_s, c_c = main()
    print "Connection received at ", datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(c_r)
    print "All Data sent after %.12f secs" % (d_s - c_r)
    print "Connection closed after %.12f secs" % (c_c - d_s)
```

Running this code won't help me reproduce the problem because my client still can get data from socket buffer, which is kind of obviously by just following the code. The only difference is that in tcp dump it goes like this:

client request

server ack

server push

client ack

server fin, ack

I'm wondering is there a way to send fin, ack right after push without "letting" client to sent ack? Can it be done using python?

Comment: A FIN does not cause loss of the prior data. You can't even notice it at the receiver unti you're read all the prior data. It is a bug in your code. You are in -non-blocking mode, so you should remove the inner `Whie Teue` loop at POLLIN, and only read when you get a new POLLIN. At present you are treating 'no data' as 'end of stream'.

Comment: @user207421 Yes, I know that by itself FIN won't cause any data loss and my client should be able to process events in the order they were received, but it happens that there is like no POLLIN nor POLLPRI at all, because read buffer is empty, and i'm guessing the small delay between PUSH and FIN,ACK may cause some race condition?
With inner POLLIN loop - you're right, my  bad

Comment: You will get a POLLIN when the FIN arrives. If there was such a race condition nothing would work.